Unable to build Signal-CLI due to Node.js version warning even though the correct version is nstalled
I am trying to install Signal-CLI, a command-line interface for the Signal messenger app by cloning its repository and building it using Gradle.
Here are the steps I followed:
Cloned the repository:
git clone https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli.git  
cd signal-cli

Ran the build command:
./gradlew build

The output of the build process was as follows:
.
.
.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 35s
16 actionable tasks: 13 executed, 3 up-to-date
mise WARN  **missing: node@20.11.1**

I checked my Node.js version to ensure that it matches:
node --version
v20.11.1

Even though the correct version of Node.js is installed (v20.11.1), the warning message persists.

What is your Ubuntu version? How was node v20.11.1 installed? is it located in a standard system path, or is it (for example) installed locally and aliased (aliases are typically not expanded in build scripts)?

Hi, thanks a lot for the response. It seems that I had globally installed Node.js 22, but locally in that file, I'm using Node.js 20.11.1 if I understood it correctly. Now it works, thanks again
